# Python NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined

Tags: python

```
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 1039, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 976, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\pyfile\pyfilecode\code.py", line 213, in output_thread
    message = unicode(message, errors='ignore')
              ^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined
```

first i have error unicode is not defined,,after follow some suggestion on stackoverflow ,, im changing unicode to str ,but again it have error "TypeError: decoding str is not supported"

so how to fix this error
thanks you

NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This error indicates (in a roundabout way; please see the linked duplicate for details) that the code is **not compatible with Python 3**, which in turn means that it is **at least three years out of date**. Please try to find a different library; and **read the documentation** for libraries before trying to use them, in order to understand the compatibility requirements.

Comment: If `pyfile` means [this thing](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyfile/) for example (which is what turns up for me when I try to search for it), you will notice that it is **almost ten** years old, and didn't get past "pre-alpha" stage of development at the time. These sorts of things should be a red flag to try to find something else to use to solve the problem. But even then, if the problem is "help, I can't use someone else's Python program out of box", then that is **not a question about writing code**, but a question about that piece of software; it is **off topic** here.

Comment: (Please see [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for more specific details on what questions are appropriate on Stack Overflow.)